# Denial of service for proxy /sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, proxy, ddos, denial-of-service

I develop a proxy, which runs queries on sql server.

I.e. the users "talks" to proxy ,and proxy sends the client`s requests to the sql server.

I am wondering how to prevent the proxy to be blocked, if one of its clients sends requests which are not legal. In this case sql server will block the proxy ,since eventually the requests are sent from the proxy`s IP. But other proxy clients will not be able to access the proxy ,since the proxy will be blocked. I want to permit the proxy to work as usual,but rather block only the client who attacked.

Comment: Your question is confusing so I want to clarify it first.  You were saying that you created some sort of proxy.  You want to allow the proxy but block them by client?  If thats the case do you impersonate a user in your proxy so it passes that credential to your SQL Server?

Comment: @Raymund The SQL server sees a proxy IP so us I understand it can't differentiate between clients.Or it can?

Comment: Could you point us to the part of the documentation that says MSSQL will block a network-address when it 'sends requests which are not legal' ? 
Out of curiosity, how 'complex' is your proxy ? Do you simply translate network-packets or do you fake the SQLReplies, identify the requests and then send those trough to the actual server using the same/different credentials... And why? =)

Comment: I agree with deroby, can you give more info about your proxy?  Are we talking proxy = data layer or business logic? Or is the proxy taking SQL statements, executing on a SQL server, and returning results? Or is this something more complicated?  Without having any more info, it sounds to me like your firewall or network Intrusion Detection System (IDS) is blocking your traffic to SQL server after certain events occur that it interprets as an attack.  I have never heard of SQL server blocking activity based on "requests which are not legal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways through the same proxy will be blocked..
I am giving two reasons here..

First, (please specify Version of SQL)

If MS SQL (above 2005) there is a configuration step in server properties, there you can explicitly specify proxy account of SQL Server...(its username and password only)
Using the Security mode with SQL Server with Windows Authentication..
The SQL Server will check credentials of the system which is sending request, and then will allow

Second, if there are firewalls(network firewall, not local).. you have to contact your network admin..
He will block all proxy with specified exceptions.

Blocking Individual user(IP) its a network security topic, it is not possible using SQL Server..

But new versions do support that facility also.. will be costly option if you upgrade.. :)

Comment: I don't think the proxy-account stuff has anything to do with the proxy-things the OP is describing !?!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think you should simply ask to close this question as you're premise is wrong to start with.